# How to safely cancel the current alarm from a PendingIntent?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I know it is not a new question nut I think it's slight different from others ,Here trying to cancel the current alarm from pendingIntent but in my case app get crashed.

In this app I am trying to stop the alarm on button click .but I got the following error .

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:132)
        at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
        at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4900)
        at com.aviz.www.reminder.Activity_Classes.AlarmActivity.stopAlarm(AlarmActivity.java:132)
        at com.aviz.www.reminder.Activity_Classes.WakeUpScreen$1.onClick(WakeUpScreen.java:44)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

AlarmActivity.java

```
 public void stopAlarm() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmActivity.this, mAlarmId, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
    }
```

AlarmReceiver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context,WakeUpScreen.class);
        context.startActivity(intent1);
        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmUri == null) {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();

    }
}
```

WakeUpScreen.java

```
mStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                alarmActivity.stopAlarm();
            }
        });
```

I tried some solutions which related to my error but I can't solve this can anyone help me to fix this .

Comment: please see the detailed error log @VicJordan

Comment: Can you please help me in this @KlinglKang

Answer (score 0):

Do this to cancel alarm

```
 public static void cancelReminder(Context context,Class<?> cls)
    {
        // Disable a receiver

        ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, cls);
        PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();

        pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
                PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED,
                PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, cls);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, DAILY_REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE_2, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(pendingIntent);
        pendingIntent.cancel();
    }
```

Comment: what should I give in the place of  "DAILY_REMINDER_REQUEST_CODE_2" ? @faran.javed

Comment: replace this with "mAlarmId".

Comment: how to call this method from WakeUpScreen.java ,what are the parameters should  I give  to call this method ..I am new to android please get me detaild

Comment: cancelAlarm(getContext(),AlarmReceiver.class)

Comment: after applying this code ,The alarm tone is not stopped and it's keep on ringing and also the upcoming alarms also not get activated ,Can you please help me in this @faran.javed